# DOMXPath Query returns no results

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

I have a very hard time understanding RegEx, and XPath seems to have me just as confused.

The Html that belongs to `$htmlsrc` :

```
<div class="text" style="font-family:monospace;">
<ol>
<li style="font-weight: normal; vertical-align:top;">
<div style="font: normal normal 1em/1.2em monospace; margin:0; padding:0; background:none; vertical-align:top;">
sQrNWk8+aiRtcn/gFM9ptAf8m3NcRf4av4m76rUZeAA=
</div>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

The PHP that is querying for the string:

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($htmlsrc);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
        $tags = $xpath->query('//div/ol/li/div');
        var_dump($tags);
```

I'd really like to return `sQrNWk8+aiRtcn/gFM9ptAf8m3NcRf4av4m76rUZeAA=` however the `var_dump($tags)` simply shows an empty object:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#24 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: That's not empty; it says the DOMNodeList has a length of 1. So I assume your actual DOMNode is the first (and only) item in the list, i.e. `$tags->item(0)`?

Comment: `$tags->item(0)` shows the item but how do you access the keys?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a stupid question. That worked I guess I just did not look hard enough. Thank you @Wiseguy